# Before Update Trigger Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a trigger that accomplishes the following

Examines the value of the field ACTION_TYPE in the row which is having an update requested

If the row (prior to update) has an ACTION_TYPE that's null, I want to insert the value/string "Change".

If the row (prior to update) has an ACTION_TYPE that contains the string 'Add', I want to keep that value in-tact.

If the row (prior to update) has an ACTION_TYPE that contains the string 'Change', I want to keep that value in-tact.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tbl8_change
ON HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE
BEFORE UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

IF ((SELECT ACTION_TYPE FROM HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE 
WHERE 
inserted.HID = HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.HID) == NULL) THEN
INSERT INTO HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE (ACTION_TYPE)
VALUES ('Changed')
WHERE inserted.HID = HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.HID; 


IF ((SELECT ACTION_TYPE FROM HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE 
WHERE 
inserted.HID = HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.HID) == 'Changed') THEN
INSERT INTO HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE (ACTION_TYPE)
VALUES ('Changed')
WHERE inserted.HID = HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.HID; 


IF ((SELECT ACTION_TYPE FROM HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE 
WHERE 
inserted.HID = HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.HID) == 'Add') THEN
INSERT INTO HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE (ACTION_TYPE)
VALUES ('Add')
WHERE inserted.HID = HOLIDAY_DATE_TABLE.HID; 

END
```

My syntax is a little off, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of linking the inserted table to the base table, you could just check the deleted table.   Also, if you do an INSERT instead of an UPDATE, your existing row will remain in the table.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have `BEFORE` triggers..... only `AFTER / ON` or `INSTEAD OF ....`

Comment: Check out `INSTEAD OF` trigger .. [Using INSTEAD OF trigger](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1804/using-instead-of-triggers-in-sql-server-for-dml-operations/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `AFTER` trigger with the same effect;

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_hdt ON holiday_date_table 
AFTER UPDATE AS 
BEGIN
  UPDATE hdt SET hdt.action_type='Change'
  FROM holiday_date_table hdt JOIN inserted i ON hdt.id = i.id
  WHERE hdt.action_type IS NULL 
END;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a272f/1).

Basically what it does is to join all updated rows with the table itself, and change the appropriate value of the matches.

Comment: Don't think your solution will work based on Dave requirement not to update when the initial value is `Add`.

Comment: @t_m The SQLfiddle shows just that, the `Add` row does not change.

Comment: @JoachinIsaksson .. I may have mis-understood the OP but I was thinking the update to be .. `UPDATE holiday_date_table SET ACTION_TYPE='Change';` and not using another column.